# Guidance on complex query

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble writing this query. I've figured out how to achieve this with multiple queries but am wondering if it's possible to do it in a single query.

- My goal is to order the results by range.
- The left two columns pertain to group_id = 1, where as the right 2 columns pertain to group_id = 2
- if range1 is positive, range2 should be the same number but negative
- if there are two rows with the same group 1, and range they should not be grouped. (see range2 value: -40)

**Dataset:**

```
table: group_data

group_id   | range  | user_value
1          | 5      | 26  
1          | -15    | 29  
1          | 15     | 30  
2          | -40    | 12  
2          | -15    | 20  
2          | -5     | 15  
2          | -40    | 10
```

**My expected Result**

```
range1 | user_value1 | user_value2 | range2
-15    | 29          |             | 15
5      | 26          | 15          | -5
15     | 30          | 20          | -15
40     |             | 12          | -40
40     |             | 10          | -40
```

This is what I've come up with so far.

```
SELECT A.range1, A.user_value1, B.user_value2, B.range2 FROM
(
SELECT
    @row_number1:=@row_number1+1 AS RowNumber1,
    g.range as range1,
    g.user_value as user_value1
FROM 
    group_data g
(SELECT @row_number1:=0)AS x 
WHERE 
    g.group_id = 1 AND
    g.range = '-15'
ORDER BY
    g.range DESC
) as A
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT 
    @row_number2:=@row_number2+1 AS RowNumber2,
    g.user_value as user_value2,
    g.range as range2
FROM 
    group_data g
(SELECT @row_number2:=0)AS y
WHERE 
    g.group_id = 2 AND
    g.range = '15'
ORDER BY
    g.range DESC
) as B
ON A.RowNumber1=B.RowNumber2
```

This returns:

```
range1 | user_value1 | user_value2 | range2
-15    | 29          | (null)      | (null)
```

With -15 and 15 switched to 5 and -5, it returns:

```
range1 | user_value1 | user_value2 | range2
5      | 26          | 15          | -5
```

Comment: This seems like a potentially interesting question, but I can't figure out what your logic is.  Can you explain it more thoroughly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the data and expected results you have provided, I think this query will do what you want. It uses a `UNION` to simulate a `FULL OUTER JOIN` (which MySQL doesn't support) on `group_data` to itself, where the left side has `group_id=1` and the right `group_id=2`.

```
(SELECT r1.range AS range1, r1.user_value AS user_value1,
       r2.user_value AS user_value2, COALESCE(r2.range, -r1.range) AS range2
FROM       
    (SELECT *
     FROM group_data
     WHERE group_id = 1) r1
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT *
     FROM group_data
     WHERE group_id = 2) r2
ON r1.range = -r2.range)
UNION
(SELECT COALESCE(r1.range, -r2.range) AS range1, r1.user_value AS user_value1,
       r2.user_value AS user_value2, r2.range AS range2
FROM       
    (SELECT *
     FROM group_data
     WHERE group_id = 1) r1
RIGHT JOIN
    (SELECT *
     FROM group_data
     WHERE group_id = 2) r2
ON r1.range = -r2.range)
ORDER BY range1
```

Output:

```
range1  user_value1     user_value2     range2
-15     29              (null)          15
5       26              15              -5
15      30              20              -15
40      (null)          12              -40
40      (null)          10              -40
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/86abae/7)

Comment: This is exactly what I was attempting to achieve! I was actually trying FULL OUTER JOIN and was wondering why it wasn't working... Now I know :) Thanks again!